# how can i bundle my app with Route of react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

[image]

As those images, the first one, the page will render the route for component named content. And the second won't render with Redirect correctly, how can i solve this problem? Thank you first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Switch`:

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

...

return (
  <div>
    <Header />

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/content" component={Content} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/content" push />
    </Switch>

    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

It will in the end do what you tried to do.

Comment: @mantis sure! If I helped please upvote or accept the answer.